Need/Want to Replace My Valve Cover & Plenum Gaskets
My car is a 2007 Toyota 4-Runner (Limited), 6-Cyl, 2WD with about 150K miles.
Per subject title, I recently noticed some oil seepage from my passenger side valve cover - apparently this is a not-uncommon occurrence for this engine design :--(
So I need to replace the valve cover gasket on that side, and may as well do the other side at same time, which entails removing the plenum cover, so...all three for the project.
I could handle the passenger side on my own, I think, but the driver's side appears to be a little more involved with more tubes, bolts, hoses, and other thingamabobs, and I can't find any write-ups with sufficient detail about all the steps involved to allow me to feel comfortable enough to take on.
I've done quite a bit of searching online...if anyone reading is aware of a good, thorough, detailed write-up or video that might help me feel more confident about taking on the driver's side, I'd appreciate a pointer to it.  Again, please, not just anything...I've already seen them all, including one where I am pretty sure the phone camera was taped to his dog's snout.
Thanks...

Are you asking exact steps to do this, or for pointers on how to logically do this without getting yourself in past your comfort level?

Ideally the first (like a recipe for making a souffle i can follow).  But I'd be interested in the 2nd, especially if it is already out there somewhere.  My expectations are low, though, since I have a copy of the factory service manual and access to Prodemand.com subscription and neither of those cover in any meaningful detail.  Kind of surprising, at least to me.
